# Sublime Text Syntax highlithing JS in PHP

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

Hy there,
Since several days, the Syntax Highlighting in Sublime Text seems a bit messed up.

[image: wrong syntax highlighting]

Without the `<?php echo $mytitle; ?>` it's how it should be:

[image: how it should be]

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: This has been fixed in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages) recently. You can follow the instructions on the repo to manually update your PHP syntax definition files to fix it immediately, or alternatively wait for the next ST3 release.

Comment: Thanks! That did it!

Comment: Just in case someone doesn't want to upgrade from the git repo, and if it is possible to do so, closing the script tags then opening new script tags seems to be a work around.